# Collapsing margin on menu overflow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to prevent my menu from overlapping onto itself when the viewport gets small and the menu items get pushed to the next line. Seems like a simple problem but I have spent hours on this problem with no avail.

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">NavItem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">NavItem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">NavItem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">NavItem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">NavItem</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Now shrink your window and the items all overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `nav a{}` to `nav li{}`:

```css
nav li {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jftf8a39/7/).

Comment: There’s already another rule for `nav li`, so in this case it’s better to merge them.